# I declare a variable and cannot use it inside of the switch statement

Tags: c#, .net, scope, switch-statement

```
string gr = comboBox1.ValueMember;
decimal sum = 0M;
try
{
    decimal rite = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    decimal left = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    string swr = "Please enter REAL a number, can be with decimals";
    label2.Text = swr;
}
switch (gr)
{
    case "X":

        sum = rite * left;
        break;
    case "/":

        break;
    case "*":
        break;
    case "-":
        break;
    default:

        break;

}
answerText.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

I'm  having problems modifying other variables outside of the switch statement - EX. rite, left; 
Every time i try compiling the code ,it shows up with the error message "the name 'left' does not exist in the current context." and the same thing with the integer rite.

Comment: Please don't put "C#" in front of a title to indicate that it's about C#. That's what we use tags for here on SO.

Comment: one tip its spelled right not rite :P

Answer (score 5):

rite and left are only accessible within the scope where they are declared, i.e. inside the try block.

You need to do something like this

```
    decimal rite = 0m;
    decimal left = 0m;
    try
    {
        rite = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
        left = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        string swr = "Please enter REAL a number, can be with decimals";
        label2.Text = swr;
    }
```

although this is not really enough, since you must decide what values you want in rite and left if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

`left` and `rite` only exist inside the `try` code block.

Answer (score 0):

rite and left are local to the inside of your try statement.  You need to declare them outside of your try statement and then assign their values inside.

eg .

```
    string gr = comboBox1.ValueMember;
    decimal sum = 0M;
    decimal rite= 0M;
    decimal left= 0M;
    try
    {
        rite = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
        left = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        string swr = "Please enter REAL a number, can be with decimals";
        label2.Text = swr;
    }
    switch (gr)
    {
        case "X":

            sum = rite * left;
            break;
        case "/":

            break;
        case "*":
            break;
        case "-":
            break;
        default:

            break;

    }
    answerText.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
}
```

Comment: This code is a bit wrong. `left` and `right` are used outside of `try`-`catch`, and they may be uninitialized by the time you get to `switch`. Initialization is necessary at declaration.

Comment: I'm guessing also that there potentially should be  a return statement inside the catch to prevent the rest of the calculation from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you have declared `rite` (I think you mean "right"...) and `left` inside the scope of a try/catch block.  What happens if that first call to `Convert.ToDecimal` fails?  Well, then `rite` has never been assigned and `left` has never even been declared.  You need to bring them up a level and declare them outside the try/catch.  Just do the assignment from within the try block.

Aside from that, you should be exiting the function if an error occurs as the code that comes later expects `rite` and `left` to be valid, which they won't be if that catch handler executes.

Answer (score 0):

Put the declaration of "rite" and "left" along with gr and sum.

Answer (score 0):

They are declared in `try` block and therefore are scoped to it.
Also, what would you expect either of them to be when there is an exception in `try` block?
They need to be initialized. (I assumed you're fine with zeroes as default values.)

Move them out:

```
    string gr = comboBox1.ValueMember;
    decimal left = 0M, right = 0M, sum = 0M; // assuming you want zeroes by default
    try
    {
        right = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
        left = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        string swr = "Please enter REAL a number, can be with decimals";
        label2.Text = swr;
    }
    switch (gr)
    {
        case "X":

            sum = right * left;
            break;
        case "/":

            break;
        case "*":
            break;
        case "-":
            break;
        default:

            break;

    }
```

P.S. Saving one character (`rite` instead of `right`) is not worth the effort, really.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring left and right in a try statement so they dont exist outside of the try statement.

```
        decimal rite;
        decimal left;

        try
        {
           rite = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
           left = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            string swr = "Please enter REAL a number, can be with decimals";
            label2.Text = swr;
        }
```

This is the correct answer.
Its called variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

the two variables rite,left are declared as local just for try block and switch block can't access it,

you should declare them to be accessible by the two blocks

```
decimal rite=0m;
decimal left=0m;
        try
        {
            rite = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            left = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            string swr = "Please enter REAL a number, can be with decimals";
            label2.Text = swr;
        }
        switch (gr)
        {
            case "X":

                sum = rite * left;
                break;
            case "/":

                break;
            case "*":
                break;
            case "-":
                break;
            default:

                break;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either include all the logic (switch) inside the try block or move the variable declaration outside of the try block.